# how to submit the form after name check availability?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

my code is working fine!
this is my jsp page when i submit the form, based on name availability,it has to submit,
for example if name is available for storing ,the form has to submit otherwise form should not submit.
in jsp:

```
    <form action="<%=editCourseURL%>" method="post" id="register-form" >
    <div class="label1">Course Name</div>
    <input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" value=" "/>&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" id="submit1" value="check availability" />&nbsp; 
    <div id="message" ></div> <br />
    <div class="label2">Course Description</div>
    <input type="text" id="cdesc" name="cdesc" value=""/><br/>
    <div class="label3">Start Date</div>
    <input type="date" name="sdate" id="sdate" value=""/><br/>
    <div class="label4">End Date</div>
    <input type="date" id="edate" name="edate" value="" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <liferay-ui:success key="key" message="message" />
    <portlet:renderURL var="homeURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/course/view.jsp"></portlet:param>
    </portlet:renderURL>
    <portlet:resourceURL var="resourceURL"></portlet:resourceURL>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#register-form").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            cname: "required",
            cdesc: "required",
            sdate: "required",
            edate: "required"
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            cname: "<p><font color=red>Please enter course  name</p></font>",
            cdesc: "<p><font color=red>Please enter course description</p></font>",
            sdate: "<p><font color=red>please enter start date</p></font>",
            edate: "<p><font color=red>Please enter end date</p></font>"
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
        $("#submit1").click(function(){
             var nameVal = jQuery("#cname").val();

               jQuery.ajax({
                        url :'<%=resourceURL%>',
                        data:{cname:nameVal},
                        type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                     success: function(data){ 
                         {
                            if(nameVal==data["cname"])
                            {

                                $("#message").html("<font color=red>course name already exist.</font>");
                                return true;
                            }   
                            else

                                    $("#message").html("<font color=green>Course name available</font>");  
                                 return false;
                         }
                   }
                    });
              });
        });

</script>

    <liferay-ui:success key="del" message="course-created-sucessfully" />
  <%

        }

  %>
```

please can any body help me? i have to submit the form based on availability of the course name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `<form>`, you have two different buttons that both contain the `type="submit"` attribute.  This means that clicking either button will try to submit your whole form.

```
<input type="submit" id="submit1" value="check availability" />
```

Since you only want this first button to do a remote check based on your `.click()` handler, you'll need to prevent it from submitting the form.  You do this by simply changing it to a `type="button"`.

```
<input type="button" id="submit1" value="check availability" />
```

Comment: @sunny, I misunderstood what you were asking.  See my edited answer above.

Comment: hai form is submititng but the course name is already taken then my form has not to submit. what ever u said is right! even though the instead 'button' submit also working.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should use submit event...

```
    <form action="<%=editCourseURL%>" method="post" id="register-form" >
    <div class="label1">Course Name</div>
    <input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" value=" "/>&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" id="submit1" value="check availability" />&nbsp; 
    <div id="message" ></div> <br />
    <div class="label2">Course Description</div>
    <input type="text" id="cdesc" name="cdesc" value=""/><br/>
    <div class="label3">Start Date</div>
    <input type="date" name="sdate" id="sdate" value=""/><br/>
    <div class="label4">End Date</div>
    <input type="date" id="edate" name="edate" value="" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <liferay-ui:success key="key" message="message" />
    <portlet:renderURL var="homeURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/course/view.jsp"></portlet:param>
    </portlet:renderURL>
    <portlet:resourceURL var="resourceURL"></portlet:resourceURL>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#register-form").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            cname: "required",
            cdesc: "required",
            sdate: "required",
            edate: "required"
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            cname: "<p><font color=red>Please enter course  name</p></font>",
            cdesc: "<p><font color=red>Please enter course description</p></font>",
            sdate: "<p><font color=red>please enter start date</p></font>",
            edate: "<p><font color=red>Please enter end date</p></font>"
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    }).submit(function(event){
             var nameVal = jQuery("#cname").val();

               jQuery.ajax({
                        url :'<%=resourceURL%>',
                        data:{cname:nameVal},
                        type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                     success: function(data){ 
                         {
                            if(nameVal==data["cname"])
                            {

                                $("#message").html("<font color=red>course name already exist.</font>");
                                return true;
                            }   
                            else

                                    $("#message").html("<font color=green>Course name available</font>");  
                                 event.preventDefault();
                                 return false;
                         }
                   }
                    });
              });
        });

</script>

    <liferay-ui:success key="del" message="course-created-sucessfully" />
  <%

        }

  %>
```

Comment: Technically this is not problem, so your comment has no sense, and should be after first post...

Comment: iam technically poor.i dont know any thing about these ajax and jquery and json. i simpilly tried..

Comment: @Krzysiek keeping 2 submit buttons inside one form makes any sense? Technically

Comment: now i have removed submit button i took button. when course name is already taken still my course is submiting the form.please help me some one

Comment: is there any one restricted not to take 2 submits inside form? its working! u can check!

Comment: @LuckyBoy Why I shouldn't use 2 submit buttons i 1 form??? This is not a mistake or a problem!! Otherwise I'm trying to only solve problem - not searching for others.